# Get plain text and append to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input and a modal, and I want to append the text plain from input to modal

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
  //$('#title-for-modal').clone().appendTo('#title-to-modal');
  console.log($("#title-for-modal").contents().appendTo('#title-to-modal').end());
  //$('#title-for-modal').append('#title-to-modal'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="item-details">
  <div class="row padding-tab-row">
    <span class="text-design col-xs-6 text-left">Add Keywords</span>
    <input id="title-for-modal" class="col-xs-6 transparent-input" type="text" name="keywords">
  </div>
</span>
<div id="next-button2" class="text-center">
  <button id="myBtn" name="next_button2" class="next-button-tab-2">Next</button>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
      <span class="close "></span>
      <p id="title-to-modal" class="modal-title"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's what i've tried, but won't works, if anyone can help me with that..thanks

Comment: There is missing a lot of information, and do you have 2 objects with the same ID ??? `title-for-modal` because that is wrong. I can also see that your `input title-for-modal` is empty

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai my bad..i've comed with update

Comment: Hope you want to pass the input to Bootstrap Modal ? if so. there is way in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get `value` from input using `.val()` method and set it to `p` element.

You need to use this:

```
$('#title-to-modal').text($('#title-for-modal').val());
```

Comment: @Apers1952, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.val()` to get value of element and `.text()` to get/set text for `p` element:

```
$('#title-to-modal').text($('#title-for-modal').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var title=$('#title-for-modal').val();
    $('#title-to-modal').text(title);
</script>
```